# JavaFX. Путь к файлу в той же папке, что и программа

Tags: java, javafx

Добрый день!
У меня проект состоит из нескольких пакетов, собственно иерархия такая:

```
src:
config.conf
  package1:
  package2:
    Start.java
    Config.java
  package3:
  ...
  packageN:
```

Стартовый класс `Start.java`, класс `Config.java` вытягивает из `config.conf` необходимые переменные.

В самом `Config.java` данные парсятся:

```
...
File file = new File("config.conf") 
...
```

Указал файл без пути, чтоб он искался в том же каталоге, где и сама программа лежит.

Так вот, пока это все запускаешь в **idea** - все прекрасно работает.

А как только создаю артифакт, программа ищет файл `config.conf` в каталоге на уровень выше.

Ну т.е. программа с конфигом лежат:

```
/path/to/file/Start.jar
/path/to/file/config.conf
```

а при запуске ищет :

```
/path/to/config.conf
```

Как это победить?

Comment: переложи в `/path/to/`

Comment: если я переложу Start.jar в /path/to/, то он будет искать конфиг в /path/ , а мне нужно чтоб конфиг искался там же где лежит jar

Comment: config.conf надо переложить

Comment: Это нарушает условие - конфиг и программа в одной папке

Comment: Попробуйте: `getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation() + "config.conf"`. Другой вариант: `Paths.get("").currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString() + "config.cong"`

Comment: В общем  ситуация такая, оказывается при такой формулировке:      
     File file = new File("config.conf")

Comment: , config.conf будет искаться не там, где лежит программа, а там - откуда ее запускают. И так как я бы хотел учесть этот факт в своей программе, то я использовал: `Path pathConfig = Paths.get(getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
        File file = new File(pathConfig.getParent() + "/config.conf");` Но теперь уперся в русские символы. Т.е. у меня `/home/user/Рабочий стол/config.conf`, а получаю я `/home/user/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b9%20%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb/config.conf`